# Backup email IMAP OU POP qual diferença?

Tags: imap, pop3

Bom pessoal estou em uma hospedagem Windows da Locaweb e estou trocando a plataforma para Linux, estou usando a ferramenta MailStore Home para fazer backup, mas não sei se posso fazer Backup IMAP ou POP, alguem sabe a diferença?

Comment: Dadas as particularidades de implementação de cada host, eu acredito que isso tenha que ser resolvido diretamente com a empresa de hospedagem, pois há muitas variáveis que podem influenciar na sua dúvida. Como o foco do site é a programação em si, e não suporte propriamente dito, infelizmente eu acho que o site acaba não sendo o meio mais adequado para uma solução satisfatória (ainda mais considerando que a resposta dada gerou nova dúvida nos comentários).

Answer (score 2):

**IMAP** é um protocolo de acesso à mensagens eletrônicas, comumente utilizado em webmail ou ainda com algum cliente corretamente configurado. Tem uma característica interessante de que as mensagens ficam armazenadas no servidor e o protocolo permite gerenciá-las, fornecendo acesso às pastas e mensagens. As pesquisas por mensagens são realizadas diretamente no servidor e é possível ainda compartilhar espaço de armazenamento de mensagens entre várias caixas postais. Uma desvantagem reside no fato de que é necessário sempre acesso ao servidor para acessar as mensagens, dado que não é feito download das mesmas. Outra é que o espaço de armazenamento e assim, quantas mensagens podem ser guardadas, depende do servidor, já que os e-mails não ficam guardados localmente.

O **POP3** é um protocolo mais antigo e é utilizado no acesso remoto à uma caixa de e-mail. Esse protocolo permite a transferência dos e-mails da caixa remota para o armazenamento local em um computador. Cada vez que um agente deseja buscar os e-mails da caixa remota, ele deve se conectar ao servidor, autenticar e transferir as mensagens uma-a-uma, o que, normalmente, faz com que a mensagem seja apagada do servidor. Após esse processo, a ligação com o servidor é desfeita e o usuário pode ler ou realizar qualquer ação com seus e-mails localmente.

O **MailStore Home** é uma ferramenta de backup para a caixa de e-mail. Funciona tanto com o protocolo IMAP quanto com o POP3. A Locaweb possui tutorial para o uso deste software para o backup da caixa de e-mail [aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Backup_de_mensagens_com_o_MailStore). O uso do protocolo IMAP, dado sua concepção de manter os arquivos no servidor a menos que um comando explícito para apagar seja dado pelo usuário, por si só, é mais seguro para qualquer caso.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP e POP são dois protocolos de comunicação geralmente usado em troca de E-mails.

No protocolo IMAP, a aplicação que o utiliza, se conecta com o servidor de emails e realiza um sincronismo entre as mensagens em tempo real, possibilitando receber mensagens (e-mails) sem precisar se reconectar ou dar um *flush* na conexão.
Este protocolo é o mais utilizado hoje em dia, uma vez que é cada vez mais comum os usuários desejarem acessar suas caixa de email de VÁRIOS lugares diferentes. (Usando webmail, aplicativos, smartphones etc).

No protocolo POP, a aplicação que o utiliza, se conecta com o servidor de email, faz download de todas as mensagens e fecha a conexão. Assim não é possível receber mensagens em tempo real, já que só foi criado uma "cópia" dos emails do  servidor e a aplicação está trabalhando com essas cópias offline.
O protocolo POP é um pouco mais antigo e está cada vez mais sendo inutilizado. (Obviamente ainda existem aplicações que o utilizam - depende muito das regras de negócio).

Agora vai de você decidir como quer se conectar com seu servidor de emails.

Se você quiser saber mais informações sobre este assunto. Há bastante artigos na internet sobre isso.
Mas como você comentou sobre a locaweb, sugiro ler [isto aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Diferen%C3%A7as_entre_Webmail,_POP,_IMAP_e_Exchange).

Comment: mas no caso se eu fazer backup como imap ele vai puxar os arquivos que estão anexados na minha maquina, essa principal duvida.

Comment: Quais arquivos anexados na sua máquina? Com relação a backup, pela definição dos protocolos, qualquer uma das duas resultaria em um resultado satisfatório.
O que da pra imaginar é que com POP, ele baixaria todas as mensagens do servidor e email e criaria uma cópia offline, enquanto em IMAP, ao retirar as mensagens do servidor, você teria uma cópia, mas removeria permanentemente do servidor.

Comment: IMAP faz sincronismo com as mensagens do servidor. Ou seja, quando você exclui uma mensagem, você exclui realmente do servidor, e todos os usuários conectados naquela caixa de email veriam o email sumir.

Pelo POP não, já que se você exclui uma mensagem, você apenas excluiu uma cópia. Já que não há sincronismo de mensagens utilizando o protocolo POP.

Comment: Obrigado essa era duvida mais cruel, pensava que quando era realizado backup no Imap os arquivos ficam anexados apenas no servidor. obrigado